# Avoiding image objects to inherit styles dedicated to text formatting

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors

This is my first post: quite embarassing, I remember founding a solution to my own question years ago ... But,let's begin.

I have set a whole hover/link/active css for my text elements

```
a:hover {
color: #000000;
background-color:#FFFF00;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;  
}

a:active {
color: #000000;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
color: #FFFF00;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline; 
}

a:visited {
color: #000000;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

the problem is that the images on the page, with they own links, also inherit the css above.
At a first time I thougnt setting the value `border=0` would have solved the problem. I was wrong.
I'm just searching the easiest way to avoid all the images elements inheritating the css dedicated to linking text formatting.

**EDIT:**

I also tried adding the following css:

```
.img:active {
background-color: transparent;
}

.img:link {
background-color: transparent;
}

.img:hover {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

and associating the image elements in the source code with the

```
class="img"
```

but images keep inheritating the main css styles.

**EDIT 2:**

@andrea-ligios your suggestion to apply the .img class to the element containing images worked perfectly! I also implemented the :not selector. Thank you so much. Sorry, this is my first post and I forgot that inserting the whole source code would have beeeìn easier for finding a solution.

Comment: Am not pretty sure what you mean as all these styles has nothing to do with image elements ... but you are probably talking about the outline property?

Comment: @ANML And what is the answer? Of the properties in your example, none affect img elements. Except if the image doesn't exist and the browser displays the alt text instead.

Comment: HI Temani, thanks for replying. The problem is that, when I associate a link to an image, the image inherits the style I coded for the text. I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: @mr-lister the properties do affect image elements. The images exists on the same page (all transparent png), when I rollover them, they inherit the background color effect, for example.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

> the problem is that the **images on the page, *with they own links***, also inherit the css above.

So your HTML (which you should always post along with your CSS, to prevent us from doing some unneeded guessing work) should be something like this:

```xml
<a href="...">
   Some Text
</a>

<a href="...">
   <img src="..." />
</a>
```

right?

> Then and **associating the *image elements*** in the source code with the
>
> ```xml
> class="img"
> ```

So you've tried

```xml
<a href="...">
   <img class="img" src="..." />
</a>
```

? If so, it can't work, because you're assigning a class to the `<img>` element, which has nothing to do with the rules you want to override, defined for the `<a>` element.

### Solution

Simply apply the `.img` class to the `<a>` element containing images:

```xml
<a class="img" href="...">
   <img src="..." />
</a>
```

Since [**class** selectors have an **higher specificity** than **element** selectors](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), `.img` rules will override `a` rules.

That said, why simply not applying the rules instead of overriding them, with [`:not` selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)?

```css
a:not(.img):hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color:#FFFF00;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
    
a:not(.img):active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    
a:not(.img):link {
    color: #FFFF00;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
    
a:not(.img):visited {
    color: #000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```